# How to import the highlighted text from Google Search Result into Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, search, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to automatically import the highlighted text from the featured snippet on a Google search result into Google Sheets, with no luck.

[Search Result Example with Highlight](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q1Osc.png)

Please see the highlighted text above to understand what I mean.

I've tried a bunch of formulas in Google Sheets, but always get the error "Imported content is empty."

Any ideas?

I'm not very technical so a simple solution would be the best one.

Here are some of the formulas I've tried:

`=INDEX(IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=ceo+of+www.cheveuxluxury.com&num=1", "//div[@class='BNeawe s3v9rd AP7Wnd']/following-sibling::div/text()"), 1)`

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q=ceo+of+www.cheveuxluxury.com&num=1", "//div[@class='BNeawe iBp4i AP7Wnd']/text()")`

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A2, "//div[@class='g'][1]//a/h3/text()")`

`=IMPORTXML("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A2, "//div[@class='g']/div[@class='rc']/div[@class='r']/a/h3")`

`=ImportXML("https://www.google.com/search?q="&A2,"//h3/a/@href")`

Comment: PS: Here is an example of where you can see what I'm attempting to do: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cBUW0FOPBTMTjMRqiQ_e6Talz-4VNLr05JRBmTsIC90/edit#gid=0

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Anyone? I really need some help!